# Do changes to an asp page in classic asp require an iisreset?

Tags: asp-classic

If I make a change to the vb code in a classic asp page does the change get picked up automatically or is an iisreset needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Quickest answer NO you do not need to reset IIS

Answer (score 2):

Once the changed file is saved, the new code will run.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to reset IIS or build the project.

Answer (score 2):

The ASP Script engine does maintain a cache of "compiled" scripts (where the results of parsing and tokenizing etc are stored.  So that subsquent requests for the same ASP page can be processed more quickly.  However the last modified date of the ASP file forms part of the cache identity of the cached page.  Hence if the page has changed since the last request the cached item is dropped and a new one built when the next request arrives so it all works seemlessly.

So as the others very quickly said, you don't need an IISReset or even an App pool recycle.

It may be worth pointing out that as of IIS6 there are very very few circumstances where you would ever need to perform an IISReset. IISReset is massively draconian and high impact.  Most of the time when such a "reset" is needed a simple re-cycle of the appropriate application pool will do which has a far more gentle touch.

Even back on IIS5 a close equivalent of a app pool recycle could be achieved with by restarting the appropriate COM+ application.

Answer (score 0):

On Win 2003 Server (IIS6) most of the time, save the changes to the file and it works.

I have had caching problems when the files have been saved and then copied/moved to the final location which is a virtual folder in IIS.

For example:

1. Say C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myfolder\ is the physical path for the URL http:Myserver/myApp/
2. I save my files in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\ and everything works fine
3. Move/copy the files from 'test' to 'myfolder' overwriting existing files and when I access http:Myserver/myApp/ I see my old pages, not the updates.